# My wordpress theme have different layout after uploaded to server

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress theme show different layout on [production link](https://galerigadget.com/) not same like [development link](http://dev.galerigadget.com/). What's wrong from production link and how i can fix it so I can get same layout like development link?

UPDATED WITH MY SCREENSHOT:
[image: Cannot show WP HEADER BAR]

**UPDATED 12/16/2015:**

After I researched again and tested on some PCs, finally I found a bug from my theme cannot responsive when zooming on chrome/firefox and not problem from db but from style.css. So how I can fix my theme will responsive based zooming on favorite browser?

**Note: Its for desktop version not for mobile version**

Comment: Need a little more information... have you moved your new theme over from your development to your production?

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but might I suggest reducing some of your image sizes? It took a good couple of minutes to load your page, when it should really only take a couple of seconds. (Loading images that are 1480px wide and then displaying them at 200px wide is a big waste of resources)

Comment: @ChrisGleason I moved my new theme  from development to production without change anything and just uploaded and activated like usually.

Comment: Does your theme have an import/export settings functionality?

Comment: @vard No. It doesn't have.

Comment: Could you look into your wp_options table and see if you can find the option that register your theme settings and see if it is serialized?

Comment: @vard Already checked, I don't get two rows like template and stylesheet on my wp_options table.

Comment: I guess a query like `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE %galeri%` should bring you the options related to your theme. If one look like [a serialized string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php#example-5855) copy the content and add it to your question.

Comment: By the way how did you imported the database in production? Did you manually changed the url in sql export or used a tool like SearchDBReplace ?

Comment: @vard    
Finally, I have found a bug for my theme cannot responsive when zooming. How I can fix it?

Comment: WP admin bar probably showing because you're currently logged into the blog on the dev box, but not on the main page. OR. the main page has a plugin disabling the admin bar

Comment: @madivad please recheck my updated description above

Comment: @user3077416 You can use the following meta do disable zooming: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">`

Comment: Try this code. It may help.
`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">`

Comment: @nitishThakrar thanks its worked for zooming out not for zooming in. How I can fix it?

Comment: It will work for both.
User-scalable = No so it will not allow user to scale.
width = device-width
initial-scale = 1.0 and maximum-scale = 1.0 so it will not allow user to zoom in or out.

What is your problem here I cannot understand.
Please share your link here so I can justify the issue.

Comment: @nitishThakrar http://dev.galerigadget.com/

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't provided enough information. What I would suggest for the moment (at least) is jump onto Google Chrome and check the development tools/tab... Inspect each page and see what's different. Check your paddings, margins, etc.

Is your development on a windows box? PHP versions, apache, almost everything has an impact.

Comment: I moved my new theme from development to production without change anything and just uploaded and activated like usually

Comment: believe me, I know the feeling... post back with more information. PHP versions for a start. Did you develop on a windows box? Your page is likely on a linux server. I know THEY SHOULD be the same, but I've experienced this as well, and it comes down to stupid little things

Comment: Our server using PHP Version 5.3.10 and using linux server. Could you check my screenshot above?

Comment: @user3077416 I've come back to this today and seen that they're now presenting the same (other than differences in your database). Care to update your post as to what your problem was or to ad an answer yourself?

Comment: Finally, I have found a bug for my theme cannot responsive when zooming. How I can fix it?